# An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host beautifulsoup scraping

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

im scraping from this website https://www.bi.go.id/id/statistik/informasi-kurs/transaksi-bi/Default.aspx to get kurs price table
[image]
[image]
with selenium and bs4,but when im trying to get the table i got error like this

> ChunkedEncodingError: ("Connection broken: ConnectionResetError(10054,
> 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None,
> 10054, None)", ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was
> forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))

and this is my code

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.bi.go.id/id/statistik/informasi-kurs/transaksi-bi/Default.aspx")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

driver.implicitly_wait(10) #secs


# click "usd"

book = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,"selectPeriod")))
sel = Select(book)
sel.select_by_value("range")

bookk = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,"ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_g_6c89d4ad_107f_437d_bd54_8fda17b556bf_ctl00_ddlmatauang1")))
sel = Select(bookk)
sel.select_by_value("USD  ")

driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

start_date = driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_g_6c89d4ad_107f_437d_bd54_8fda17b556bf_ctl00_txtFrom")
start_date.send_keys("20-Nov-15")
end_date = driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_g_6c89d4ad_107f_437d_bd54_8fda17b556bf_ctl00_txtTo")
end_date.send_keys(time.strftime("%d-%m-%Y"))

time.sleep(5)
buttons = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//input[@value='Cari']")
buttons[1].click()

src = driver.page_source # gets the html source of the page
headers = {
    #"Referer": "https://id.investing.com/commodities/gold-historical-data",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:80.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/80.0",
    "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"
}
parser = BeautifulSoup(src,"lxml") # initialize the parser and parse the source "src"
url = "https://www.bi.go.id/id/statistik/informasi-kurs/transaksi-bi/Default.aspx"
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
html = r.text
table = parser.find("table", attrs={"class" : "table1"}) # A list of attributes that you want to check in a tag)
rows = table.find_all('tr')
data = []
for row in rows[1:]:
    cols = row.find_all('td')
    cols = [ele.text.strip() for ele in cols]
    data.append([ele for ele in cols if ele])
    
result = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['nilai', 'kurs_jual', 'kurs_beli', 'tanggal'])
result.to_csv("kurs1.csv", index=False)

df = pd.read_csv("kurs1.csv")
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', df.shape[0]+1)
print(df)
```

what should i do? please help me,im stuck since weeks ago! thank you in advance
the csv file shouldve been like this
[image]

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to explain what data you are trying to get from the website, perhaps how to access it on the website itself, and an example showing what your output CSV should hold.

Comment: @MartinEvans done!please check it out

Comment: Looks like they are blocking all attempts at screenscraping

Comment: do you have any solution for me sir,please im stuck